# How do I scrape multiple URLs from a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, loops, web-scraping, rvest

I scraped a website already and made a dataframe from it that only contains one column. The dataframe is called "urldataframe", while the column that contains all of the urls is called "individualrace_url".

Here is some of my data, the links are formatted as a character currently in the dataframe, urldataframe.
[image]

Here is the first two links:
https://sites.google.com/site/hscrrarchive/arca-1/2007-arca-re-max-series-season/2007-arca-200
https://sites.google.com/site/hscrrarchive/arca-1/2007-arca-re-max-series-season/2007-construct-corps-palm-beach-grading-250

How do I create a scraper that goes through my dataframe of links one by one? I'm not sure if a for loop is the way to go about this or not. If I can use a for loop, what am I doing wrong?

```
res_all <- NULL

for (realtest.Event in racename) {
    urlrunning = paste0(realtest.Event)
    
  scrapinghere = read_html(urlrunning)
    
  putithere <- tibble(
      bubba = scrapinghere %>% html_nodes("#sites-canvas-main-content td:nth-child(2)") %>% html_text(),
      bubba2 = scrapinghere %>% html_node("#sites-canvas-main-content td:nth-child(1)")) %>% html_text()
  
  
  res_all <- bind_rows(res_all, putithere)
  }
```

I'm hoping that it would go through the loop of each url that I have in the dataframe. Every url has the same nodes, I'm pretty sure my issue is setting up the loop itself.

Comment: Difficult to help you without sample data / links to test on

Comment: Hi @TomHoel, just added sample data and links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scraping the tables from the two links without loop.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(janitor)

df <- tibble(
  links = c("https://sites.google.com/site/hscrrarchive/arca-1/2007-arca-re-max-series-season/2007-arca-200", 
            "https://sites.google.com/site/hscrrarchive/arca-1/2007-arca-re-max-series-season/2007-construct-corps-palm-beach-grading-250")
)

get_ARCA <- function(link) {
  link %>% 
    read_html() %>% 
    html_table() %>% 
    pluck(4) %>% 
    row_to_names(1) %>% 
    clean_names()
}

map_dfr(df$links, get_ARCA)

# A tibble: 81 × 9
   finish start car_number driver            sponsor                                make      laps  led   status 
   <chr>  <chr> <chr>      <chr>             <chr>                                  <chr>     <chr> <chr> <chr>  
 1 1      2     5          Bobby Gerhart     Lucas Oil                              Chevrolet 80    54    Running
 2 2      20    93         Marc Mitchell     Ergon                                  Pontiac   80    5     Running
 3 3      12    3          Jeremy Clements   Harrison's Work Wear-1 Stop Conv-Saxon Chevrolet 80    0     Running
 4 4      13    39         David Ragan       AAA                                    Ford      80    0     Running
 5 5      3     46         Frank Kimmel      Tri-State Motorsports-Pork             Ford      80    0     Running
 6 6      19    31         Timothy Peters    Cometic Gaskets-Okuma                  Chevrolet 80    0     Running
 7 7      31    16         Justin Allgaier   AG Tech-Trashman-Hoosier Tire Midwest  Chevrolet 80    0     Running
 8 8      14    4          Scott Lagasse Jr. Cunningham Motorsports                 Dodge     80    0     Running
 9 9      11    47         Phillip McGilton  SI Performance-Gould's Electric        Chevrolet 80    0     Running
10 10     17    2          Michael McDowell  Hillcrest Capital Partners             Dodge     80    0     Running
# … with 71 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Other variations:

#1 Separate in a list

```
res_separate <- map(df$links, get_ARCA)
```

#2 As data frames inside of the original data frame

```
res_in_df <- df %>% 
  mutate(content = map(links, get_ARCA))
```

Comment: Thank you! Would there be a way to separate these two pages in the code rather than having them stacked on each other as well? I think having both would be beneficial. Again, thank you for the help!

Comment: I have added some additional variations you can try out. To get a single page you could just `get_ARCA(a link)` though.

Answer (score 1):

A `for` loop is ok, I think in your case the closing parentheses for the `tibble` are at the wrong place. Another pattern I like is to use `purrr::map_dfr` which returns a data.frame. Here my untested code as no data is provided:

```
library(purrr)

res_all <- set_names(racename) %>% 
  map_dfr(function(realtest.Event) {
    scrapinghere = read_html(realtest.Event)
    
    tibble(
      bubba = scrapinghere %>% html_nodes("#sites-canvas-main-content td:nth-child(2)") %>% html_text(),
      bubba2 = scrapinghere %>% html_node("#sites-canvas-main-content td:nth-child(1)") %>% html_text()
    )
  }, .id = "racename")
```

I've used the `.id` argument to provide an additional column to the returned data.frame with the value of `realtest.Event` so that you know to which url the results belong to.

Comment: for some reason I'm still getting the following error: Error: `x` must be a string of length 1. Any tips to look at @starja ?

Comment: when running what, the for loop or map_dfr? which part of the code returns the error? can you provide example data?